# Redirect from stripe invoice page to the web app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments, payment, invoice

I'm working on stripe payments,I will get a stipe url from backend so I need to redirect from the web app to this stripe url for payments ,But my doubt is after successful payment How can I redirect them back to the web app or if it fails I want to show error message in the web app.Is it possible?

I have tried Stripe confirmPayment Method but it is showing Invalid value for stripe.confirmPayment(): elements should have a mounted Payment Element or Express Checkout Element.
But I think this is not the proper way implementing this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share more details about what you're trying to do? You mention "invoice page" but that describe trying to use `stripe.confirmPayment()`. Are you trying to pay invoices using your own customer payment form with Elements, or something else? If so, yes you need some Elements and you'd need the `client_secret` from the invoice's PaymentIntent. If you share more details it will be easier to offer more specific help.

Comment: I'm not using any custom elements im'using this https://invoice.stripe.com/i/someids here and this will be the url I'll get from backend as response I only need to redirect to link and show the payment page ,but the payment page is their page not ,our web application page ,So how can I redirect after successful payment? Do you understood?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The hosted Invoice page is designed to be accessed from an email, there is no way to set up a redirect from it (there is *no* redirect out of the domain).

I would suggest building your own form with Elements using the Payment Intent that is related to your Invoice.